# android how to get gridview item size

Tags: android

I want to get GridView item size in my application. I only know I can get the item size in callback:

```
private class GridViewItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int viewh = view.getHeight();
            int vieww = view.getWidth();
            Log.d(TAG, view.getWidth() + "," + view.getHeight() + 
                    " > position:(" +view.getX() + " , " + view.getY() + ")");
        }
    }
```

but I can't get its item size in onResume, even I tried in handler:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what) {
        case UPDATE_GRIDVIEW:
            View itemView = mGridView.getChildAt(0); //this will return null pointer;
            final FrameLayout.LayoutParams  lp= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(itemView.getLayoutParams());
            lp.setMargins( -3, 0, 0, 0);
            selectorView.setLayoutParams(lp);   
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

I triggered the handler in onResume method

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = UPDATE_GRIDVIEW;
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    super.onResume();
}
```

I even tried to call GridView's methods getSelectedItem() etc..., Can't make it either. Could you please give me some advices, and what's reason?  and how to get the gridview item size?

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

So we just need to stretch row. Which we can do, by calculating how much rowHeight should be if we know height of GridView and rowsCount.

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   int rowsCount;

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       View itemView = convertView;
       if (itemView == null) {
           itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);            
           int height = parent.getHeight();
           if (height > 0) {
               LayoutParams layoutParams = itemView.getLayoutParams();
               layoutParams.height = (int) (height / rowsCount);
           } // for the 1st item parent.getHeight() is not calculated yet       
       }
   }
```

Comment: I intend to get size in Activity; after get the size, I will reset my selectorView according to the GridView item size.  thanks